# Sentence Explanation - Seneca's On the Shortness of Life

Tags: terminology, quotes

> I realized that your grief should not be intruded upon while it was fresh and agonizing, in case the consolations themselves should rouse and inflame it: **for an illness too nothing** is more harmful than premature treatment.

If I'm understanding correctly, Seneca refers to consolation of a fresh and agonizing wound as "premature treatment" and therefore, he should abstain from doing so to not make the situation worse. This indicates that premature consolation is less harmful than an "illness too nothing"? That doesn't make much sense to me.

If consolation is less harmful than a "too nothing" illness, than why isn't he consoling his mother?

What am I missing here? The sentence after the colon is contradicting the first.

Comment: Seems like a poor translation to me.

Comment: At best there's a comma missing after "too".

Comment: @HotLicks yea I see that now. Pausing at “too” helps. Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a “too noth­ing” be­cause that is not a
syn­tac­tic con­stituent. You have mis­parsed the struc­ture. Think
of the word *too* there as mean­ing *also*, and then try re­read­ing
it with com­mas to ei­ther side of that *also*. Or put that *also*
out front in­stead.

In other words, it is say­ing that just as it is for grief, **also**
for an ill­ness is there noth­ing more harm­ful than pre­ma­ture
treat­ment, that pre­ma­ture treat­ment is the worst thing for both
of those two.